# Deleting Records in Joined Multiple Tables in a DataBase

Tags: sqlite

How can I delete a particular record in a DataBase where 6 tables are joined among each other.

Comment: Please be more specific - include a SELECT that selects the rows that you'd like deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to create the FOREIGN KEY (with "**[ON DELETE CASCADE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933119%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)**" action) Constraint(s) that will automatically remove records from the corresponding referenced tables. Take a look at the “[FOREIGN KEY Constraints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175464.aspx)” Books Online / MSDN topic for more information.

Answer (score -1):

Do it within a transaction. Referential integrity isn't checked until the transaction is closed:

```
begin;
delete from table1 where ...;
delete from table2 where ...;
delete from table3 where ...;
commit;
```

Comment: the OP is asking how to delete records from a set of joined tables.